# Null with NOT in sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've a problem in using `NULL` with `NOT` in sub-query, the code is:

```
Create table #FirstTable(i int)
Create table #secondTable(i int)
insert into #FirstTable(i) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
insert into #secondTable(i) values (2),(3),(null)

select * from #FirstTable where i not in (select i from secondTable);
```

The expected result would be `1,4,5` but it gives null, how can I get the expected value?
The question is somehow similar to the referred question but specifically that question is including joints with different values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `not exists` is recommended approach rather than using `not in`

```
select * from #FirstTable f
where not exists(select 1 from #secondTable
                 where i = f.i)
```

Comment: There is already an object named '#FirstTable' in the database, SQL server is giving this error.

Comment: @ZiaUllah Because you are trying to create this table again with you `create table` statement. You need to remove it.

Comment: Ahh @michal sorry, I forgot to remove the create table code haha, it worked, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

its because you have a `null` value in your 2nd table. filter it using `isnull()`

```
Create table #FirstTable(i int)
Create table #secondTable(i int)
insert into #FirstTable(i) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
insert into #secondTable(i) values (2),(3),(null)

select * from #FirstTable where i not in (select isnull(i, 0) from #secondTable);

drop table #secondTable
drop table #FirstTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `where i is not null` clause to your subquery to avoid this problem:

```
select * 
from #FirstTable 
where i not in (select i 
                from #secondTable 
                where i is not null);
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a0cbfdf27289818886c175a7f410e031)